# How can I create a link to a local directory on a locally-run web site

Tags: php, windows, iis, directory

I have a directory full of subfolders that contain multiple tiff images.  My goal is to have a web interface that will allow me to click a link and open the directory with windows explorer.

$value = "HTML Link";

computerx is where the images are stored / filepath is the actual path to the data

if I look a the properties of the link it is proper, but the link will not work on my webpage
file://computerx/TIFF/WATER/PROJECT10001/

but if I copy and paste it back into internet explorer it will work.

Comment: Security.... a web page loaded from an `http://` address should never be able to load up a `file://` address - that'd allow malicious sites to load any file from a local machine's drive.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a virtual directory or web site that points to that folder.

Then enable directory browsing. That will allow users to see the list of files available and also to browse/download them.

Comment: This is a virtual direcory with directory browsing enabled. It does work when I manually enter the file://computerx/TIFF/WATER/PROJECT10001/ but I cannot make the link work, but it shows it properly when I look at the properties of it.